# How to update Android Studio in Linux

Tags: linux, android-studio

I'm on Linux Mint KDE and want to update Android Studio. When I update PHPStorm (also a JetBrains product) the directory always has the version number so there is no overwriting. Android Studio does not. Do I just overwrite the old directory? Or delete it first? Or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you can simply use the built in update function found in

Help -> Check for Update...

If it is not a small patch, but a larger update (happens from time to time) you need to download a new archive.  For me it was always safe to remove (or rename) the old installation folder first since all your configuration settings are stored in

~/.AndroidStudio

anyways and Android Studio will automatically reuse these (or ask you if it shall migrate them).

I am using Android Studio for 2 years now and that was always working for me.

BTW: I use IntelliJ IDEA as well and it also has the version number in the installation folder.